# How to change the color of any function in desmos function grapher without the need to delete and recreate the function all the time?

Tags: desmos

I don't see any way to change the color of some function without the need to delete it and recreate it.

I think and believe that there must be a better, easier, faster and more convenient way to change the color of any function without the need to delete it and recreate it all the time but if there is better and easier way to do that then what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Change Color or Style](https://support.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/202529149-Change-Color-or-Style) (UNTESTED - I think you would need to be signed in, or click on Edit List (the gear icon) first):

> To change the color or style of an expression, long-hold the colored icon to the left of the expression. Clicking the icon will hide or show the expression.

[image: Desmos guidance]